# MYSQL - Group all value with alike value

Tags: sql, mysql

I am trying to group all items in MYSQL with the same value like,

```
Calamba - 15
Cabuyao - 12
Sta Rosa - 10
```

This is what I've tried,

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, present_address
FROM `emply1`
WHERE present_address LIKE '%CALAMBA%'
```

The problem is I have to group it by typing a city manually, `'%calamba%'` then another user will be added and I have to manually code it again.

This is the sample database I am having now.

```
Column name: present_address

Row 1: BUNK HOUSE #4 CANLUBANG, CALAMBA CITY, LAGUNA

Row 2: 349 BRGY. PARIAN, CALAMBA, LAGUNA

Row 3: 349 BRGY. MAMATID, CABUYAO CITY, LAGUNA
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: `like '%Calamba%' OR like '%Cabuyao%' OR like '%Sta Rosa%'`  just add more "like something" conditions using OR. At least this is what I think you are asking for.

Comment: you can add `city` column to contain this data to make it easier to `group by`

Comment: Try to use separate columns for those strings. I don't know what the different strings in your sample data represent. Let's say, your address consists of country, zip code, town, street and house number. Create 5 countries for those 5 parts and save every part in its correpsonding column. Thus, you will get rid of the ugly `LIKE` conditions and can just use an `IN` clause instead.

Comment: yeahh too much LIKE statement makes the code ugly but I think creating VIEWS will be another solution

Answer (score -1):

I have used the ChatGPT application and the result is,

```
SELECT 
  (
CASE 
    WHEN present_address LIKE '%CALAMBA%' THEN 'Calamba'
    WHEN present_address LIKE '%CABUYAO%' THEN 'Cabuyao'
    WHEN present_address LIKE '%STA ROSA%' THEN 'Sta Rosa'
    WHEN present_address LIKE '%SAN PEDRO%' THEN 'San Pedro'
    WHEN present_address LIKE '%Batangas%' THEN 'Batangas'
    ELSE 'Other'
  END
) AS city,
COUNT(*) AS count
FROM emply1
GROUP BY city
```

Thanks again everyone.

Comment: It's obviously a wrong query. I generally doubt this `CASE` idea is correct. This will likely be very slow. It also misses an `UPPER` around the address column to make the conditions case-insensitive. As said in comment above, improve your DB design rather than writing bad queries.

Comment: @jonas: LIKE is not case sensitive (for Mysql)

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, sir @JonasMetzler .. maybe creating Views will be the proper solution for fast query.

Comment: I don't think so, but you can try